# Undefined index: username error when user has logged out

Tags: php, html, session, authentication, logout

This is part of my index.php code, it prints the current users login $SESSION. But when the user clicks logout it gives an error message saying "Undefined index: username" on line x. 
What does this mean and how can I fix it?

```
 <?php

  $dbname = 'lw17894'; # Change to your username
  $dbuser = 'lw17894';
  $dbpass = 'obscure';
  $dbhost = 'localhost';

  $link = mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass )
  or die( "Unable to Connect to '$dbhost'" );

  mysqli_select_db( $link, $dbname )
  or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");


    if($_SESSION['username']) {
        echo "Welcome, User: {$_SESSION['username']}";
    } else {
        echo "User not logged in!";
    }
    ?>
```

and heres my logout.php code:

```
<?php
session_start()
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
session_unset(); 
session_destroy();
echo "<h1>You are logged out!</h1>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<h2><strong>You will be redirected back to Home in 3 seconds</strong></h2>";
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=index.php" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No doubt a dupe, but no session_start(), and you should use isset or !empty to test your session key, because when you destroy or start a fresh session, you'll have no existing session key: username, and hence have an undefined index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the session is getting destroyed, try using isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['username']) in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

When the user isn't logged in you're still checking the session variable for a username key.

Check if there's a session, and that the user name key exists in the session like this.

```
  $dbname = 'lw17894'; # Change to your username
  $dbuser = 'lw17894';
  $dbpass = 'obscure';
  $dbhost = 'localhost';

  $link = mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass )
  or die( "Unable to Connect to '$dbhost'" );

  mysqli_select_db( $link, $dbname )
  or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");

    if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        if(array_key_exists ('username' , $_SESSION ) {
            echo "Welcome, User: {$_SESSION['username']}";
        } else {
            echo "User not logged in!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd drop the session_status() condition and wrapper, and place session_start() at the beginning of the file.